# "Cannot include control characters in a HTTP header" using Parse

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, parse-platform

I've implemented a login manager in my game using Parse, and everything worked well.

So I've added an online leaderboard, but now each time Unity executes a method like this:

```cs
void UpdateOnlineScore(string id, int newScore)  
{
    var query = ParseObject.GetQuery("tableName").WhereEqualTo("userid", id);

    query.FirstAsync().ContinueWith(t => {

        if (t.IsFaulted)
        {
            Debug.LogWarning("ID not found");

            // user stats not found create from scratch 
        } 
        else 
        {
            Debug.Log("Record found");

            ParseObject obj = t.Result;
            int savedScore = (int) obj.Get<int>("score");

            // check record
        }
    });
}
```

it stops at `query.FirstAsync().ContinueWith(...)` throwing this exception:

> **ArgumentException: Cannot include control characters in a HTTP header, either as key or value.**
>   UnityEngine.WWW.CheckSecurityOnHeaders (System.String[] headers) (at C:/BuildAgent/work/d63dfc6385190b60/Runtime/Export/WWW.cs:98)
>   UnityEngine.WWW..ctor (System.String url, System.Byte[] postData, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2 headers) (at C:/BuildAgent/work/d63dfc6385190b60/artifacts/EditorGenerated/Utils.cs:88)
>   Parse.PlatformHooks.GenerateWWWInstance (System.String uri, System.Byte[] bytes, System.Collections.Hashtable headerTable)
>   Parse.PlatformHooks+<>c__DisplayClass30+<>c__DisplayClass36.b__29 ()
>   Parse.PlatformHooks+d__3c.MoveNext ()
>   UnityEngine.Debug:LogException(Exception)
>   Parse.d__3c:MoveNext()

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.
What's strange is that I get this error only debugging on *Web Player* platform.
On *Windows Standalone* it doesn't show up.

Am I missing something?

I'm usign Unity 4.6.0f3.

Comment: Try creating a minimal project where you attempt this simple update and nothing more to verify that it is not some external thing that is causing the problem.

Comment: @SirBraneDamuj I'll give this a try. I'm using another working project as guideline, I don't understand why this don't work.

Comment: @SirBraneDamuj I did it and nothing has changed. So I've tried using a different Parse account (that I made for testing) and now the login part works. I really don't understand what's going on...

Comment: Is `id` coming back from Parse at some point? Perhaps there is some garbage data which is being included in the HTTP request somehow. Kinda reaching at this point though. Seems very bizarre.

Comment: @SirBraneDamuj Probably, but I don't know how to check the HTTP request. Anyway it's not an `id` problem, I get the same error while signing in, creating a new account and requesting the password recovery.